# Simplest circuit to detect 5 V pulse

Tags: contact, spike, edge-detection

I have a mechanical assembly with 24 switches, limit switches, selectors, etc. and this assembly along with a box filled with electronics will go and suffer a very long shock and vibration test.

I want to be sure the 24 contacts will never ever create a slight contact that could be interpreted by the MCU as an input signal so I will detour all harnesses to a..

I was going to use 2 Saleae logic analyzers on 2 laptops and monitor the signals and confirm it’s all dead in the log after. But the app crashes sometimes so it’s not reliable.

What super simple circuit could monitor this, maybe with 24 latched LEDs to watch for a super quick spike? It's 24x 110 V with 1 ground, but I will put all signals on optocouplers at 5 V.

Comment: Seems like you already have everything you need. You have an MCU you are worried about; the possibility of interpreting things wrong. So all you have to do is attach everything together and jumble the works. If the MCU makes a false interpretation, you have your answer and you will have used your exact setup to figure it out. Since I see nothing at all with respect to how these switches are surrounded by circuitry, I'm left with nothing to add. Lots of possible 'super simple'. But none certain to be of any help. And it's a waste to just throw mud at a wall to see what sticks.

Comment: The following information in the question seems a bit vague (a) ``a slight contact`` (b) ``a super quick spike?``. To help get a better answer can you [edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/699944/edit) the question to include what duration of _spike duration_ you need to detect during the test.

Comment: Also, can the MCU software ignore input signals which are activated for less then a certain duration to ignore _spikes_ which may occur during Shock and Vibration testing (or normal use)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CD4043 and CD4044 are quad set-reset flipflops or latches.  Each latch can capture a pulse width less than 1 us.  Six packages will cover 24 signals.  The outputs can be multiplexed into a uC, or drive low-current LEDs.  Use whichever part matches the logic polarity of your system.

A single switch-plus-resistor resets all 24 latches - start the tumble - go away - come back 24 hours later - look for red lights.

Comment: You may find this open-source CD4000 series reference card set I had drawn up handy: https://hackaday.io/project/191205-4000-series-logic-reference-cards. If the plate that's your avatar is yours, we're in the same city at the moment :)

Comment: Mine since the 70's.  Yea Ohio!

Comment: Nice Kuba! That is very very helpful +1.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to be sure the 24 contacts will never ever create a slight
> contact **that could be interpreted by the MCU as an input signal**

From your question, what you are trying to detect during environmental testing is:

- Are there false switch presses long enough for MCU will respond to (a system test)

Rather than "Will the switches ever produce a false press even as a fast glitch" (just a test of the switch component).

---

You describe the switch inputs as going into an MCU. It is unlikely that the MCU will use the switch levels directly without first debouncing the switch levels. (To see it another way, if your MCU doesn't debounce input switch levels then it almost always should.)

A typical debouncing method is to repeatedly read a switch level and only accept it as pressed/released when seen as steady for a period on many milliseconds. So the MCU would not respond to microseconds-long glitches from switches. There's then no point detecting such events as they would not be fault conditions, they would be switch noise rejected by the debouncing filter. Reporting them as faults would instead be a failure of the test process.

The first thing to establish is how your MCU's switch input debouncing works. You can do this several ways:

- Inspection. The MCU spec' or software source files will tell you.
- Empirical testing. Connect a pulse generator to a switch input and deliver increasingly long pulses until the switch input is recognised. With debouncing, it is likely that 10 us would be ignored while 50 ms will be recognised.

From that, you can specify and make a circuit that only responds to switch pulses that your MCU would respond to.

Having noise in a system is not a fault or test failure. There's noise on the supply rails, noise on inputs and outputs. The faults and failures are from having noise that (a) interferes with system behaviour or (b) reduces the quality of the system function to an unacceptable level.